# How to close a dialog in code?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, swt

So I'm making a eclipse plugin and I have a made my own dialog by extending the dialog class.

My dialog basically populates a treeview with data from a server. Sometimes the data cannot be populated (because the server is down) so my treeview is empty.

I have made another dialog appear reporting the error if I am unable to connect to the server. 
My problem is that I would like to close the initial dialog when I press ok in the error dialog.

I have not been able to find a good way to do this. 
I have tried setting setBlockOnOpen to false.
I have tried calling cancelPressed.
Neither of them have worked. 
I called them in the createDialogArea function.

Any Ideas on how I could get this to work?

Comment: Can you please post some your custom dialog code?

Comment: I don't have the latest code with me. But here is some code I modified, it should be easy to see what I mean. http://pastebin.com/gPKca2M7 As you can see if the exception for couldnotconnectoserver occurs it returns null. The three commented lines are the three different solutions i tried but they didnt work.

Comment: have you try to use  this method dismiss() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `close` call after the dialog creation has finished. You can do this by using this code:

```java
parent.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      close();
    }
  });
```

in your `createDialogArea` method. However the dialog may appear briefly. It would be better to do your check before creating the dialog.

Comment: thanks that worked. (although i did use cancelpressed() because it would be better)

Answer (score 2):

It is basically user cancelling dialog. you need to invoke `cancelPressed()` so it will be consistent handling if you have any code that depends on `returnCode`

```
if(noDataLoaded){
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
        cancelPressed():
    }
    });
}
```